# Get specific records from parse database using Http Request?

Tags: javascript, api, parse-platform

I want to fetch specific records from parse database using http request based on some specific column.

I run this url

> https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm

in browser provided on parse.com REST API Guide by providing my parse app id and javascript key. I used **my own table name** instead of GameScore. As I want to fetch specific records on the base of other column not by object id. So I replace the objectid of above url with day=13. So final url is

> https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/ChallengeTask?day=13.

Where **day** is **column name** in my table having datatype `Number`. What I meant by above query is that it will return me all records with having day equal to `13`. But when I execute, it returned me all records of table instead of which have day equal to `13`. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in the browser

`https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/classes/ChallengeTask?where={"day":13}`